# Laravel throws an error on setting a not null string field to empty string

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, factory, laravel-5.5, faker

When I try to execute this code (excerpt):

```
// ####_##_##_######_create_items_table.php
$table->string('seller_sku')->default('')->unique();

// ItemFactory.php
return [
  'seller_sku' => $faker->optional($default = '')->word,
];
```

and run: `php artisan migrate:refresh --seed`

it yields:

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column
'seller_sku' cannot be null (SQL: insert into `items` (`name`,
`seller_sku`, `category_id`, `current_prize`, `winter`, `updated_at`,
`created_at`) values (facilis, , 44, 131, 1,
2018-03-03 12:18:22, 2018-03-03 12:18:22))
```

Why is that happening and how can I solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

the problem is because first you are telling the laravel to set  a default value `''` after that you set a `unique key` .. What if there are to rows with `value = ''` they wont be unique anymore .. unique keys cannot have any default value.. thats why you are getting an error

Comment: I had no idea that empty strings counts in uniqueness, I thought they would be equivalent to `null` in that aspect.

Comment: no `unique keys` cant have same values even if it is `null or ''`

Comment: No it can have multiple `null`. Tested and certified.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved using `$faker->optional(null,'')->word`. [The faker documentations](https://github.com/fzaninotto/Faker#modifiers) are kinda misleading, especially for somebody becoming from Python.

But anyway it just happens that duplicate empty strings are not allowed in a not null column so I ended up doing this (excerpt):

```
// ####_##_##_######_create_items_table.php
$table->string('seller_sku')->nullable()->unique();

// ItemFactory.php
return [
  'seller_sku' => $faker->unique()->optional()->word,
];
```

I shared the solution that somebody might get in a likewise confusion.